# Choosing yarn version prefix on the fly

Tags: versioning, yarnpkg, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to tag some of my commits and `yarn version` does a pretty good job here. By default, the prefix of the git tag is `v`. I'm curious whether there is a way to choose a prefix whenever `yarn version` is called.

I know I can do this:

```
yarn config set version-tag-prefix "other-prefix"
```

and switch it when necessary, but I'm curious if there is a quicker way. The point of this is to trigger different scripts on the build machine (using Bitbucket Pipelines) when a different tag prefix is pushed (production, staging, test).

[CONTEXT] My current idea is:

- v0.0.0 for production
- s0.0.0 for staging
- t0.0.0 for test

or:

- v1.0.0 for production
- v2.0.0 for staging
- v3.0.0 for test

and I'm not too happy with either but I want to use tags to indicate which build I'd like to trigger.